# keep session time out long as possible with asp.net 4.0 with c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, asp.net-4.0

i have made one asp.net 4.0 crm web site. i have one big problem with session handling it's expires session unexpectly how ever i applied one technique that from `keepalive.ashx` that keep session alive as long as possible.

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="keepalive" %>

using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.SessionState;

public class keepalive : IHttpHandler, IRequiresSessionState
{

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        if (context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            // authenticated sessions
            context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
            context.Response.Write("Auth:" + context.Session.SessionID);
        }
        else
        {
            // guest
            context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
            context.Response.Write("NoAuth:" + context.Session.SessionID);
        }
    }

    public bool IsReusable {
        get {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

this is how i calling :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var interval = null;
        (function () {
            // keep me alive
            interval = setInterval(function () {
                $.get('../keepalive.ashx', function (d) {
                    $('#response').append(d + '<br/>');
                });
            }, 30000);
        })();


        // If we want to stop the interval....
        function Stop() {
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
</script>
```

but problem is same there. unexpectlly session go out.

this is my web.config line :

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" timeout="525600"/>
```

but does't giving satisfied solution.

please help me...

Answer (score 1):

Try this (KeepSessionAlive.ashx can be blank):

```
function KeepSessionAlive() 
{
    $.get(ResolveUrl('~/KeepSessionAlive.ashx'), function (data) { });
}

$(function () {
    setInterval(KeepSessionAlive, 300000); //5 minutes
});


function ResolveUrl(url)
{
    if (url.indexOf("~/") == 0) 
    {
        url = baseUrl + url.substring(2);
    }
    return url;
}
```